# How to use an app.get request to render a page that's located in a different folder

Tags: javascript, express

I have two folders:

- HTML
- JS

Both are on the same level. In my JS folder, I have a file (called ccc.js) and I want to use an app.get request to render a page (called credit_c_c.html) from my HTML folder.

When I use the following code, I receive an error message "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\LYind\thisislindaye.com\Scriptcredit_c_c.html'"

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/credit_c_c.html');
});
```

When I realize this syntax returns the directory that the currently executing script is in from __dirname, I've tried the following:

```
    res.sendFile('../HTML/credit_c_c.html');
```

However, this snippet of code returned a string.

I was wondering what is the proper syntax to create a path for the app.get request to render a file that's in a different folder than the folder that the current script is in?

Thanks in advance,
Linda

Comment: Try `__dirName + "/../HTML/credit_c_c.html"`

Comment: Perfect, thanks Phil!